# Force contents of a new subsection to start right after previous subsection and not on a new page

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking

I am writing my resume and I am separating each section by `\subsection*{}`. The problem is that after writing the first and second subsections, the contents of the third subsection do not fit in the remaining space left on the first page so it moves the whole contents of the third section to a new page. I like the third subsection to start right after the second subsection ends and then those line that don't fit on the first page to be moved to the second page.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\pagestyle{plain}
\parindent 0pt
\parskip \baselineskip
\newcommand{\place}[1]{{\sc #1}}
\newcommand{\header}[1]{\underline{\large\sc #1}}
\newcommand{\entry}[2]{{\emph{#1}}&{ #2 }\\[0.22cm]}

\begin{document}
\vspace{-2cm}

\begin{center}{\Large \bf \sc My name}\\[.18cm] {\it \today} \\[.3cm]
Phone: (111) 111-1111
\hfill College of Computer and Information Science \\
Email: {\tt xxx@xxx.neu.edu} 
\hfill \place{xxx University}, Boston MA \\[-2cm]
\end{center}\hrulefill

\def\todo#1{{\color{red}[TODO: #1]}}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\vspace{-.9cm}

\subsection*{Research interests}

\begin{itemize}
\vspace{-.5cm}
\item Statistical ...\\
\vspace{-.75cm}
\item R-based ...
\end{itemize}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\vspace{-1cm}
\subsection*{Education}
\vspace{-.25cm}
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{1.5cm}p{14.5cm}}
\entry{2016-current} {PhD candidate, My Field, \place{My  University}, Country
\newline Advisor: Y. XXX}

\entry{2014}{MS, My Field, \place{My University}, Country
\newline Thesis: {\it ``My thesis"}
\newline Advisor: O. UUU
}

\entry{2010}{BS. My Field, \place{My University}, Country.
\newline Diploma: {\it ``My diploma title"}
\newline Advisor: S. DDD
}
\end{tabular}

\vspace{-0.5cm}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\subsection*{Experience}
\vspace{-0.5cm}
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{1.5cm}p{14.5cm}}

\entry{06/2017-present}{First Experience. \place{My University}, Country. 
\begin{itemize} 
\vspace{-0.25cm}
\item MS course ``Name of Course". Grading, Office hours.
\end{itemize}
\vspace{-0.25cm}
}

\entry{06/2017-09/2017}{Internship. \place{Name of Company}, Country 
\begin{itemize} 
\vspace{-0.25cm}
\item Causal inference in networks inferred from noisy bio-molecular measurements.
\end{itemize}
\vspace{-0.25cm}
}

\entry{01/2017-04/2016}{Internship. \place{Name of Company}, Country 
\begin{itemize} 
\vspace{-0.25cm}
\item Causal inference in networks inferred from noisy bio-molecular measurements.
\end{itemize}
\vspace{-0.25cm}
}

\entry{01/2017-04/2016}{Internship. \place{Name of Company}, Country 
\begin{itemize} 
\vspace{-0.25cm}
\item Causal inference in networks inferred from noisy bio-molecular measurements.
\end{itemize}
\vspace{-0.25cm}
}

\entry{02/2016-09/2016}{First Experience. \place{My University}, Country. 
\begin{itemize} 
\vspace{-0.25cm}
\item MS course ``Name of Course". Grading, Office hours.
\end{itemize}
\vspace{-0.25cm}
}

\entry{02/2009-09/2010}{First Experience. \place{My University}, Country. 
\begin{itemize} 
\vspace{-0.25cm}
\item MS course ``Name of Course". Grading, Office hours.
\end{itemize}
\vspace{-0.25cm}
}

\entry{09/2009-11/2009}{First Experience. \place{My University}, Country. 
\begin{itemize} 
\vspace{-0.25cm}
\item MS course ``Name of Course". Grading, Office hours.
\end{itemize}
\vspace{-0.25cm}
}

\entry{02/2009-09/2012}{First Experience. \place{My University}, Country. 
\begin{itemize} 
\vspace{-0.25cm}
\item MS course ``Name of Course". Grading, Office hours.
\end{itemize}
\vspace{-0.25cm}
}

\end{tabular}

\end{document}


\end{document}
```

And here is a picture of how the result of running the code look like in LaTeX:

[image]

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contents of your sections are inside a `tabular` environment which does not allow page breaks. 
To enable page breaks in tables you need for example the `longtable` package. To use it in your case, add `\usepackage{longtable}` in your preamble and replace `\begin{tabular}` and `\end{tabular}` by `\begin{longtable}` and `\end{longtable}` respectively.